# Почему return функции присваивается переменной со второго раза (node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть таблица в mysql, и мне нужно получить последнее непустое значение столбца. Если значение в столбце таблицы не является пустым сразу, то return функции присваивается переменной сразу, если 1 или более пустых значений в столбце таблицы, то со второго раза. Почему так происходит? Код прилагается.

```
function backLastData() {
    let tempo = 1
    return function getLastData(message) {
        const isEmpty = Object.values(message[message.length - tempo].dataValues).every(item => item === null || item === '' || item === "NULL");
        if (isEmpty) {
            tempo++;
            getLastData(message);
        } else {
            return message[message.length - tempo].dataValues;
        }
        return
    }
}
module.exports.backLastData = backLastData;
```

// получение данных из таблицы

```
const message3 = await dataDef.findAll({ attributes: ['message3'] });

const getLastData = backLastData();
```

если 1 или более пустых значений

```
const finalText3 = await getLastData(message3);
console.log(finalText3) - возвращает undefined
console.log(await getLastData(message3)) - возвращает верное значение

const finalText = await getLastData(message3);
console.log(finalText) - возвращает верное значение
console.log(await getLastData(message3)) - возвращает верное значение
```

если нет пустых значений

```
const finalText3 = await getLastData(message3);
console.log(finalText3) - возвращает верное значение
console.log(await getLastData(message3)) - возвращает верное значение

const finalText = await getLastData(message3);
console.log(finalText) - возвращает верное значение
console.log(await getLastData(message3)) - возвращает верное значение
```

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: По правилам Stackoverflow.ru вопросы задаются на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так?

```
function backLastData() {
    let tempo = 1
    return function getLastData(message) {
        const isEmpty = Object.values(message[message.length - tempo].dataValues).every(item => item === null || item === '' || item === "NULL");
        if (isEmpty) {
            tempo++;
            return getLastData(message);
        }
        return message[message.length - tempo].dataValues;
    }
}
```

Или даже вот так

```
function backLastData() {
    const os = new Set([null, '', "NULL"])
    let tempo = 1
    return function getLastData(message) {
        const o = message[message.length - tempo].dataValues
        const isEmpty = Object.values(o).every(item => os.has(item));
        if (isEmpty) {
            tempo++;
            return getLastData(message);
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оба варианта рабочие